# How to register a route in laravel for SPA admin panel

Tags: laravel, routes, single-page-application

I am writing a SPA administrative panel site for example (http: // localhost) there you go there a form for entering a login and password, routes laravel handled it and the routes themselves were vue-route

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'AdminPanelController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Everything works fine, but then I decided to move it to a folder (http: // localhost / admin) and for some reason it does not work

```
Route::get('/admin/{any}', 'AdminPanelController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you moved Your whole laravel application, than you'll probably have to adjust your server settings (`DocumentRoot`). If you moved only your `AdminPanelController` than I would check if the namespaces are correct. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: No, I want to register a route for the admin panel opened at the address **/admin**. when I ask for information in the documentation of the laravel, then 404
`Route::get('search/{search}', function ($search) {
    return $search;
})->where('search', '.*');`